# Reloading Animated sprite while on the game scene Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite-sheet

While on the game play scene, when player fires, the enemy will automatically animate and have to move out from the scene. i tried alot but didn't find the solution.

here is my code.

```
     it = bulletList.iterator();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
     final Bullet b = (Bullet) it.next();

    if (b.sprite.collidesWith(enemy)) {

              engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
           enemy.animate(new long[]{100,100,100,100,100},10,14,1
             , new IAnimationListener() {
             @Override
            public void onAnimationStarted(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,int     

    pInitialLoopCount) {
                }
       @Override
              public void onAnimationLoopFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                        int pRemainingLoopCount, int
          pInitialLoopCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
        public void onAnimationFrameChanged(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                int pOldFrameIndex, int  pNewFrameIndex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
        public void onAnimationFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    detachChild(sprite);
                }
            });
                                 enemy.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                          it.remove();
                          break;
                    }
               }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

what is it that's actually happening?
i did not understand...

But i understood your code a bit.And i recommend you to remove the runonupdatethread.
And put your animation code outside the runonupdatetheard and try it.

I animate the sprite directly...

Comment: animation code is running fine outside the runonupdatethread but i want to animate it when bullet(which is also moving with animation code) hits/collides with my sprite.
"b.sprite.collidesWith(enemy)"
this function is called when the bullet hits my sprite while game is in running state. So, basically i want to update my thread when bullet hits my object But unforunately its not working.